Difference between "mit dem Auto" and "mit den Autos"
Here are some sentences from Duolingo

Die Menschen fuhren mit dem Auto nach Westdeutschland.
Warum fuhren sie mit dem Auto nach Westdeutschland?
Sie fuhren mit den Autos nach Westberlin.

The contexts don't seem to differ among these examples. I thought "mit dem Auto" was a set phrase. If that is indeed the case why and when do people use "mit den Autos"?

This is how Duolingo works. There's no logic behind those random variations.

In fact this seems more like a question about Duolingo than about German language.

Your first sentence "Die Menschen fuhren mit dem Auto nach Westdeutschland." is a singular that can have translations with two different meanings in English:

"The men drove with the car to West Germany." => this relates to a specific car, that was mentionned before.
"The men drove by car to West Germany." => this relates to the mean of transport, without specifying a particular car.

Your third sentence "Sie fuhren mit den Autos nach Westberlin." is a plural that only has one single meaning:

"The men drove with the cars to West Berlin."

By the way, if I want to be confusing, I can add that the first sentence could also be used to describe two truck drivers that are in a truck, carrying a car to West Germany... They would not be in the car, but it would still be "Die Menschen fuhren mit dem Auto nach Westdeutschland." :-)
Please anyone correct any mistake I may be doing here.

Funnily enough that is perfectly correct :D
Also your answer is better than mine. Hope it gets accepted.

I like the comparison with the English "by car". You don't say "by cars" in English no matter how many cars there are. But with "in" you have to count the actual cars: "they drove in cars" unless they all piled into a single car. If anything, it's English that's being inconsistent here.

I would read the third example sentence as meaning they drove to West Berlin with a specific collection of cars. Grammatically correct but without context or with the context of the two preceding sentences I would actually mark it as wrong and strongly prefer 'mit dem Auto' in this sentence as well.

If you use singular you are describing the mode of transportation the people use.
Sie fahren mit dem Auto.
Sie fahren mit dem Zug.
Sie fahren mit dem Fahrrad.
Sie fahren mit dem Taxi.
Sie fahren mit der Straßenbahn.
But of course, many people use many cars. So it is also fine to say that they went to west Berlin in their cars. See the plural "s" in english? That works just as well in German.
Sie fahren mit den Autos.
Sie fahren mit den Zügen.
Sie fahren mit den Fahrrädern.
Sie fahren mit den Taxis.
Sie fahren mit den Straßenbahnen.
Therefore, in my opinion "mit dem Auto" is no set phrase. Rather if you use a singular vehicle (mit dem Auto) you describe the mode of transportation. If you use the plural you literally say that multiple of those vehicles were used. Which makes sense if there are many people in need of transportation.
If you would say "Er fuhr mit den Autos." this would mean he had to stop and switch to another car. Because (in most cases) you can't drive multiple cars at once.

Thanks very much for your great answer, and thank you again for quality-checking my answer! :-)
